# TabBarIOS: onlyChild must be passed a children with exactly one child

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to react-native and I have an error trying to create TabBarIOS.
It keeps telling me *onlyChild must be passed a children with exactly one child* but my code is exactly identical with the tutorial I followed.

**index.ios.js**

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react-native');
var Welcome = require('./welcome.js');
var More = require('./more.js');

var {
  Alert,
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Component,
  TabBarIOS
} = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#f5fcff',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  button: {
    height: 44,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: '#488bec',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
    color: 'white',
    alignSelf: 'center',
  }
});

class iCareReactNative extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedTab: 'welcome'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
  <TabBarIOS selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab}>
    <TabBarIOS.Item
      selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'welcome'}
      systemIcon="featured"
      onPress={() => {
        this.setState({
          selectedTab: 'welcome'
        });
      }}>
      <Welcome/>//welcome component
    </TabBarIOS.Item>
    <TabBarIOS.Item
        selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'more'}
        systemIcon="contacts"
        onPress={() => {
          this.setState({
            selectedTab: 'more'
          });
        }}>
        <More/>//more component
    </TabBarIOS.Item>
  </TabBarIOS>
    )
  }
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('iCareReactNative', () => iCareReactNative);
```

**welcome.js**

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');

var {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  Component
} = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  description: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#123456'
  }
});

class Welcome extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.description}>
          Welcome to Welcome
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = Welcome;
```

I found that usually this error will be triggered by *TouchableHighlight* [LINK](http://willi.am/blog/2015/05/08/react-native-fix-for-invariant-violation-onlychild-must-be-passed-a-children-with-exactly-one-child/) but I didn't use any of those.

Any idea?

Comment: what does your `More` component look like ?

Comment: exactly like Welcome component, but I had 2 things changed, class Welcome -> class More, module.exports = Welcome; -> module.exports = More;

Comment: if you `console.log(Welcome, More)` in your `index.ios.js`, what comes out ?

Comment: Well it says a lot of things, http://postimg.org/image/u96i4hpdj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is triggered when a component expects a single valid React element as a child and doesn't get one. To debug this issue, you will generally look for a component that hasn't been properly imported, or whose `render` method returns `null`.

In your case, the component expecting a child and not getting one is the **selected** `TabBarIOS.Item`. If you set both `selected` props of your `TabBarIOS.Item` components to `false`, you'll see that the error disappears.

Now why doesn't it find the `Welcome` and `More` components ? Because of the comment in your render method (`//welcome component`, `//more component`). Remove the comments and the error will be solved.

I'm not sure, though, why the comments didn't trigger an exception : it should complain that some text isn't wrapped in a `Text` component. Maybe something to do with your react-native version.

Comment: Thank you, my code works now after removing the comments. My react-native version has already in the latest form, v 0.23.1, I guess you were right, something is wrong with react-native itself